# AngularJS Currently Selected Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Learning more about AngularJS everyday.

A `style` contains `style.StyleID`,`style.StyleName`,`style.EncryptedValue`

I have the following code:

```
<select data-ng-model="StyleID"
    data-ng-options="s.StyleID as s.StyleName for s in styles"
    data-ng-change="GetOptions()">
    <option value="">--Select Style--</option>
</select>
```

I need to pass `EncryptedValue` into `GetOptions()` e.g (`GetOptions(EncryptedValue)`) or be able to access something like `SelectedStyle.EncryptedValue`

How do I go about doing that?

---

**UPDATE**

Changed my code to:

```
<select data-ng-model="style"
    data-ng-options="s.StyleID as s.StyleName for s in styles"
    data-ng-change="GetOptions()">
    <option value="">--Select Style--</option>
</select>
```

My Controller:

```
$scope.GetOptions = function () 
{
    alert($scope.style);
}
```

`alert($scope.style);` returns a string of the StyleID

`alert($scope.style.StyleID);` returns `undefined`

What is going on ???

Note: `styles` is loaded via AJAX call (JSON result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to rework how you handle things in your controller but you can change your model to this:

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedStyle"
    data-ng-options="s as s.StyleName for s in styles"
    data-ng-change="GetOptions()">
    <option value="">--Select Style--</option>
</select>
```

Then in your controller, you can do this

```
$scope.GetOptions = function(){
    console.log($scope.selectedStyle.EncryptedValue)
};
```

The only thing is now if you want to reference your StyleId you have to do it this way:

```
$scope.selectedStyle.StyleId
```

Comment: `console.log($scope.selectedStyle);` returns a value - not an object. Why is that?

Comment: Can you paste exactly what styles looks like and how you load it.

Comment: Yes. The trick was `s as s.StyleName for s in styles` instead of `s.StyleID as s.StyleName for s in styles`